# Modal (Devise) for Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I Have an application in RoR and I need to make a login modal.

I´m using the gem `devise`.

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
    class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
     respond_to :js
    end
```

In the devise folder of the views, I have the sessions folder with 2 files: `_new.html.erb`  and  `new.js.erb`

**_new.html.erb**

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
      <h2 class="dark">Log in</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
      </div>

      <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
        <%= f.label :remember_me %>
      </div>
      <% end -%>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-md btn-black-line" %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
      <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**new.js.erb**

```
$('#modaldevise').html('<%= j render('new') %>');
$('#modaldevise').modal();
```

In my `application.html.erb` I use this code to use modal:

```
<div id="modaldevise" class="modal fade"></div>
```

Finally I have a side menu that have the login link:

```
<%= link_to 'Login', new_user_session_path, 'data-toggle' => "modal" , 'data-target' => "#modaldevise" %>
```

When I press the Login link, the background becomes darker and the modal is opened, but the information from the partial `_new.html.erb` is not showed.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid using `new.js.erb` and do something like this:

**application.html.erb**

```
<div id="modaldevise" class="modal fade">
  <%= render 'your_path/new' %>
</div>
```

**side menu**

```
<%= link_to 'Sign in', '#', "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target"=>"#modaldevise" %>
```

Comment: More idiomatic to Rails would be: `<%= link_to 'Sign in', '#', data: {toggle: 'modal', target: '#modaldevise' } %>`.